# Sending a specific POST Request to recieving an base64 format text file and displaying it at WebView

Tags: java, android, post, base64, android-webview

I would like to ask for help with a POST Request.
I want to send a specific post on the server, which if I will send a correct authentication, then it will send me back the image formatted in base64, then I want to show it inside WebView.

I have 2 EditText fields and one button as layout.
One textfield is for Login, and the second on is for Password.
Login is sent in the body of the message as a POST parameter with key username.
Password is encrypted with SHA-1 and sent in header in the field named authorization. With button I can send the Post request which should look like this>

> POST /download/image.php HTTP/1.1
>   Authorization: myPass
>   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>   Host: www.myweb.com

My code is here. But it is not working at all. I am new in post requests, so I really don't
 have a clue how to write it properly.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
  String login = mLoginView.getText().toString();
  String pass = mPasswordView.getText().toString();

  URL url = null;
  try {
      url = new URL("https://www.myweb.com/download/image.php");
  } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  HttpURLConnection connection = null;

  try {

      if (login.length() == 0) {
          login = "correctpass";
      }
      if (pass.length() == 0) {
          pass = "correctlogin";
      }

      //calling getter for parsing the password into SHA1 hash
      try {
          pass = (String) HashTool.getSHA1Hash(pass);
      } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

      connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
      connection.setRequestProperty("Key","username");
      DataOutputStream outputPost = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream()));
      outputPost.write(login.getBytes());

      writeStream(outputPost);

      //this getBytes method won't work
      connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(outputPost.getBytes().length);
      outputPost.close();

      connection.setDoOutput(true);
  } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();

  } finally {

      if(connection != null) // Make sure the connection is not null.
          connection.disconnect();
  }
```

This is writeStream() method. I don't know how to do it properly.

```
//method used for post request
private void writeStream(DataOutputStream out) throws IOException {
    String output = "something here??? maybe post ?";

    out.write(output.getBytes());
    out.flush();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this method send data on ***link*** as ***POST***:

```
private void executeLink(String link, String urlParameters) throws Exception{


    String response = null;

    byte[] postData       = urlParameters.getBytes( StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
    int    postDataLength = postData.length;
    URL    url            = new URL( link );
    HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput( true );
    conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );
    conn.setRequestMethod( "POST" );
    conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    conn.setRequestProperty( "charset", "utf-8");
    conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", Integer.toString( postDataLength ));
    conn.setUseCaches( false );


    try( DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream())) {
        wr.write( postData );
    }

    conn.connect();

    if(conn.getResponseCode() == 200){

        //some thing else
    }else{
        //rejected 
    }
    return response;
}
```

call method:

```
executeLink("url.link" , "param1=1&param2=val2&param2=val3")
```

Comment: Thx @Morteza. I will try it cca in 2 hours. I went to downtown tech library, to borrow some book on this topic. I would like to understand it more.